# Line number printing for log4j for JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, log4j

I am using [log4j](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) for logging in my Java project. My conversion pattern is as below.

```
ConversionPattern=%d{MMMMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p [ %C{1} - %M() - %L ] - %m%n
```

Now for all Java classes, it prints output as:

```
February 03,2012 15:18:41 DEBUG [ RadiusClientConfigBean - initialize() - 63 ] - RadiusClientsConfigBean.initialize() Called
```

But for JSP pages it prints as:

```
February 03,2012 15:19:00 DEBUG [ managevoippolicy_jsp - _jspService() - 443 ] - VoIP Policies = 4
```

which is not the actual line number of that [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) page. How can I print line numbers for JSP pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to determine the original line number from a JSP would be [JSR-45 Debugging Support for Other Languages](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=45) The JSP compiler creates a SourceMap (SMAP) which you could use. (I wouldn't recommend this for production).

AS a starting point this discussion might be helpful:

http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Read-JSR-045-SMAP-Files-Produced-by-Jasper-td2128534.html

Answer (score 2):

Your JSP is recompiled as a servlet class, so you will never be able to match them back to your original page.

Comment: Then what if I want to print line numbers of that JSP page into log file ?

Comment: As said: you aren't able to do that. That's the disadvantage of a page that is recompiled out of your control. It is not recommended to put logic in your jsp-file, but use MVC. In your controller, you do have control over the line numbers. (unless you use an AOP framework like aspectj which recompiles your code after wiring their code)